# Are there any cases where the back-seat pilot is the only one who can cause both ejections seats to fire?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, ejection-seat

In military training aircraft with a tandem seating configuration, with the instructor pilot in the back seat and the trainee pilot in the front seat, is the ejection system ever set up so that there is a mode where the back seat occupant can eject both pilots, but the front seat occupant can only eject himself/herself?

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23654/34686

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, I can't answer with certainty about what might exist, but as far as I know, NO. This would make no sense, as once the pilot is gone, why would the rear seat occupent want to hang around?

In the F-4 Phantom, (USAF versions), there was a switch in the rear cockpit (called the [Command Selector Valve](https://picclick.com/F-4-Phantom-Ejection-Seat-Cockpit-Command-Selector-Handle-223118738193.html)), that controlled whether or not the front seat ejection sequence would be triggered when the rear cockpit occupant initiated an ejection.

But the rear cockpit ejection sequence was *always* triggered if the front seat occupant ejected.

Regardless of who initiated the ejection, the rear seat would be ejected and depart the aircraft first, followed by the front seat 2 seconds later. This was to avoid the front seat rocket motor from frying the rear seat occupant.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answer addresses the exact question being asked-- perhaps would be better posted as an answer here?  --  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23654/34686

Comment: The specific answer was implied... thought that was obvious, but I edited it to state it explicitly.

Comment: re "This would make no sense, as once the pilot is gone, why would the rear seat occupant want to hang around?" --  in the present question, both seats are occupied by "pilots", but the one in front may be a inexnperienced trainee.

Comment: Which makes one tend to think of the situation that is addressed by the "Normal" mode described here https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/93617/34686 -- except the position of the "experienced" crew member versus the "inexperienced" one is reversed.