# Why is the detcord on canopies wavy?

Tags: fighter, ejection-seat

We [know](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12821/2719) that the wavy lines on the canopy are detcord, to shatter the glass in case of ejection.

**Why are they wavy?**

Comment: Perhaps it shatters a larger area per cord?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly to shatter the canopy into smaller fragments.  Straight dets might just detach a large proportion, possibly leading to unwanted severe secondary strikes on ejecting aircrew.